# Forms in Rails 3.2 and handling ajax requests callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I'm trying to do this the "rails way" since I'm learning rails and want to understant it.

Here's my "problem".

I have a simple subscription form that looks like this in **home.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(  subscribe_newsletter_path , id:'subscribe-form', remote: true) do %>
    <%= email_field(:subscription, :email, placeholder: 'ex: Giroud@Arsenal.com') %>
    <%= submit_tag("Subscribe Now!", class: 'btn btn-success') %>
<% end %>
```

My javascript in **home.js** is:

```
$('#subscribe-form')
.on('ajax:beforeSend', function(){
    console.log('before send');
})
.on('ajax:success', function(){
    console.log('success');
})
.on('ajax:complete', function(){
    console.log('complete');
})
.on('ajax:error', function(){
    console.log('fail');
})
```

my **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

and my **home_controller.rb** file looks like this ( this is where it get tricky for me )

```
response = //Response message from mailchimp API. looks like that {"error"=>"bablabla@gmail.com is already subscribed to list Testing Rails. <a href=\"http://test.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/send-email?u=test&id=test&e=test==\">Click here to update your profile.</a>", "code"=>214}

render json: response, status: '200'
```

The ajax request do get fired and my controller receive the email and send it to the mailchimp API then send it back to the browser ( status 200, I can see the json response in Chrome dev tool ) but none of the bind event get trigger.... I know it is working because when I bind the event to $(document) instead of $('#subscribe-form')it works fine...

Why?

Comment: rails 3.2 and rails.js?? are you sure? rails.js is a component of rails 2.x as I remember.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 well actually you are right, it is not rails.js I have //= require jquery_ujs in application.js . this is what I mean. Sorry for the confusion, I will edit the question.<br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion
>   of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

more: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

the way it worked for me in a rails 3.2 app, just exemples, not exact solutions for your case:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).hide();
});
```

so your issue might be in using .bind while you are using a newer Jquery version.

---

**Edit**

The `ajaxComplete()` method specifies a function to be run when an AJAX request completes.

**Note:** As of **jQuery** version **1.8**, this method should only be attached to **document**.

Unlike `ajaxSuccess()`, functions specified with the `ajaxComplete()` method will run when the request is completed, even it is not successful.

Comment: Tried with .on, doesn't work either.  But everything ( .on or .bind ) works on $(document). It just doesn't work on my form element or the submit button. :(

Comment: I want to run it on $('#subscribe-form') and not $(document), I think  this is where the problem is coming from.

Comment: look here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp, looks like from Jquery 1.8 all ajax methods have to be attached to document not to an element.. anyway, I am not a big expert in ajax and jquery.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do the "jquery way" instead then :)